# Why can't I see the php cms admin panel on heroku?

Tags: php, mysql, heroku, pdo

I have deployed my php website on heroku app.
I can view the posts images etc even I can place the order as well.
But when it comes to accessing the admin panel
I can just see the navigation bar.
But in the local host I was able to access everything smoothly.
For instance the posts that I created on

http://finwearclothing.herokuapp.com/

I was able to post them while I was on local host.
When deployed the admin panel does not display anything but just the navigation bar.

Comment: Hi there,

This probably means that you have an error happening in the page and you're not displaying the error due to the configuration of PHP. You need to Debug. You have 2 main alternatives: 1. Edit the php.ini and enable all errors OR 2. Check your server logs to understand which is the fatal error causing your page to go blank

Comment: I am using php pdo oop. I have never gave any issues in my local host but when u deploy this happens. I don't have any php.ini file as I never required this when I deployed other websites. Any fatal errors taking place are caught instantly including the warnings. But i am assuming it could be the configuration related to heroku and php itself idk but thank you for reaching out 